# Python-Weka-Wrapper3 removing attributes from arff file error

Tags: python, weka, arff

I have an arff file and I need to remove the first 5 attributes from it (without manually deleting them). I tried to use the Python-Weka-Wrapper3 as it is explained [here](https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper/api.html) which enables the filtering options of Weka, however I get an error while using the following code:

```
import weka.filters as Filter
remove = Filter(classname="weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove", options=["-R", "1,2,3,4,5"])
```

The error that I receive is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/file_loading.py", line 16, in <module>
    removing = Filter(classname="weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove", options=["-R", "last"])
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What could be the reason for this error? Also I would appreciate if anyone knows an alternative way to remove attributes from an arff file using Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to call the module object instead of the class object.

Try using:

```
from weka.filters import Filter
remove = Filter(classname="weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove", options=["-R", "1,2,3,4,5"])
```